# Is this the optimal way to guard against failed DB commits?

Tags: c#, transactions, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have a legacy method that keeps throwing an exception. It has a nested try|catch. Is this the best way to code that sort of thing:

```
public void DBCommand(string dynSQL, bool Silent)
{
    checkConnection(); //Despite the name, this "returns" void, not bool
    SqlCeCommand cmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
    SqlCeTransaction trans = GetConnection().BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Transaction = trans;

    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = dynSQL;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try 
        {
            trans.Rollback();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException sqlceex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SqlCeException ({0})", sqlceex.Message));
            CCR.LogMsgs.Append(string.Format("SqlCeException exception: {0}\r\n", sqlceex.Message));
            // Handle possible Rollback exception here
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("DBCommand Except ({0})", ex.Message));
        CCR.LogMsgs.Append(string.Format("DBCommand exception: {0}\r\n", ex.Message));
    }
}
```

?

I want to refactor this to use using statements for at least the SqlCeCommand, but for now the above is the "as-is" code. I'm seeing the general exception message 
("DBCommand Except"), never the "SqlCeException"

### UPDATE

By adding some MessageBox.Show() calls back (debug log file no longer being written for some reason), I found that this is the DDL that throws the exception:

```
ALTER TABLE CCR032713190114 ADD salvationId nvarchar(19), salvation float
```

Note: "CCR032713190114" has been proven to be a valid tablename (it exists) at this point in thecode.

Is there something wrong with this DDL that would cause a problem?

### UPDATE 2

I changed the code from this:

```
ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) ", tablename);
dbconn.DBCommand(ddl,false);
ddl = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET salvationID = {1}", tablename, string.Empty);
```

...to this:

```
ddl = string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT", tablename);
dbconn.DBCommand(ddl,false);
```

...but now, right after "*ALTER TABLE BLA ADD salvation float NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT*" I'm seeing this err msg, "*DBCommand Except (There was an error parsing the query. 
[Token line number, Token line offset,, Token in error,,])*"

What in Azure braziers is going on here?

Do I need to specify a default val after the "WITH DEFAULT" (won't '' or string.empty automatically be the default for a nvarchar column, 0.0 for a float, etc.)?

Comment: Do you know what type of exception is being thrown here?

Comment: In short ...no it is not an optimal way to handle failures. You should use a `try-catch-finally`.

Comment: @TimoGeusch: No, the ex.Message is giving me nothing.

Comment: Do the columns you're trying to add into the table already exist?

Comment: @TimoGeusch: It is first checked to see the table DOES exist, and then that those columns added do NOT yet exist.

Comment: @ClayShannon, does your account have the privileges to alter tables? Does executing the SQL add the columns? If you check that the table exists, the columns don't exist and you still get an exception and the table hasn't been altered, my next educated guess would be that you have a permissions issue.

Comment: Note that the OP's question changed with the **UPDATE**.

Comment: I guess I have to wait until this post is older, but I want to add some "bounty" points (after the fact) to both ErikEJ and IAbstract (who answered the original question) when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add two columns in same ALTER TABLE statement, must add one at a time, also good idea to specify NULL or NOT NULL (if NOT NULL, a DEFAULT may be required)

Comment: Is limiting the ALTER TABLE statement to a single column a SQL-Server specific limitation? According to this: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php
you can simultaneously add multiple columns this way:

ALTER TABLE supplier
  ADD (supplier_name varchar2(50),
       city varchar2(45));

Comment: I guess I should have tagged this question with "SQL," as it took a SQLKenner to notice that; that solved it, thanks!

Comment: Adding the NOT NULL was not greeted hospitably by SQLCE: I got "THE CONSTRAINT SPECIFIED IS NOT VALID"

Comment: Of course you can use NOT NULL, please share the full ALTER statement

Comment: ALTER TABLE Bla ADD salvationID nvarchar(19) NOT NULL. However, after removing the "NOT NULL" appendage, I get a different err msg, namely that "A column ID occurred more than once in the specification" so perhaps that was the original problem, but I don't know why eliding the "NOT NULL" would change the wording...

Comment: And I wonder if "NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT" would be a better way to go than the way the legacy code first adds the column (conditionally) and then adds a value ('' for nvarchar columns, 0.0 for float columns); I reckon so.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not ever see the `SqlCeException` then it would truly be exceptional. To keep it 'out of the way', I would do the following:

```
public void DBCommand(string dynSQL, bool Silent) {
    checkConnection(); //Despite the name, this "returns" void, not bool
    SqlCeCommand cmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
    SqlCeTransaction trans = GetConnection().BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Transaction = trans;

    var doRollback = false;
    try {
        cmd.CommandText = dynSQL;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        doRollback = true
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("DBCommand Except ({0})", ex.Message));
        CCR.LogMsgs.Append(string.Format("DBCommand exception: {0}\r\n", ex.Message));
    }
    finally {
        if(doRollback) }
            DoRollback();
        }
    }
}

void DoRollback(){
    try {
        trans.Rollback();
    }
    catch (SqlCeException sqlceex)  {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SqlCeException ({0})", sqlceex.Message));
        CCR.LogMsgs.Append(string.Format("SqlCeException exception: {0}\r\n", sqlceex.Message));
        // Handle possible Rollback exception here
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I implemented this; I'm still experiencing the same issue, but it answered my question.

Comment: I had to introduce "tramp data":

if (doRollback)
      {
       DoRollback(trans);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

  public void DoRollback(SqlCeTransaction _trans)